# High memory allocations when unregistering delegates from event in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

We are developing a game with the [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com) engine (which uses Mono for user code - our code is written in C#).

The scenario is that we have a class exposing an event, with around ~ 250 registrations to that event (each level object on the game's map registers itself to that event):

```
// Every level registers itself (around 250 levels)
ScoresDataHelper.OnScoresUpdate += HandleOnScoresUpdate;
```

When destroying this scene, every object unregisters itself from the event:

```
ScoresDataHelper.OnScoresUpdate -= HandleOnScoresUpdate;
```

When using the built-in profiler, i am seeing a huge memory allocation, digging deeper shows that it is due to the delegates being unregistered.

I suspect this is due to the fact that Delegates are immutable and when chaining them together, new instances are created ?

Here's a screenshot from Unity's profiler:

[image: Profiler]

Is there any way to avoid these memory allocations when dealing with a large number of event subscriptions?

Comment: Is that a problem? GC will kick in and collect the garbage as soon as it needs to. Btw, you want to unregister every object which subscribed to the event or only few?

Comment: Yes, it's a problem since it allocates around 3MB and also consumes time. This makes the experience of moving from the map scene to the actual gameplay take longer to start.

Comment: Umm, answer my second question please "you want to unregister every object which subscribed to the event or only few?"  Also Benjamin Gruenbaum has a good answer for you.

Comment: Yes, all should be unsubscribed. Of course there's always the option of redesigning the system to avoid 250 registrations in the first place. I just wanted to understand the issue in theory of how to handle many events being registered as it seems to generate such high memory allocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you confirmed in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587567/high-memory-allocations-when-unregistering-delegates-from-event-in-c-sharp#comment47322828_29587567) that you want to unsubscribe all the event subscriptions, there is no reason to unsubscribe it one by one.

You could just set the event to null. This will unsubscribe everything from the event without allocating any memory.

```
this.OnScoresUpdate = null;
```

One thing to note is that you can't do this from outside of the `ScoresDataHelper` class. It must be inside `ScoresDataHelper` class.

Comment: This would work in the case where no other object would subscribe to this event. Except for those 250 objects i mentioned, there may be other instances that should be kept registered. Otherwise - you're correct, this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @lysergic-acid Yes, you're right. That's why I asked you twice in comments before writing this as an answer. This will work only when you need to unsubscribe everything.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be not to use events in the first place.

```
// T,S,U is whatever your function takes and returns
private List<Func<T,S,U>> Listeners = new List<Func<T,S,U>>();
public void OnScoresUpdate(Func<T,S,U> listener){
    Listeners.Add(listener);
}

// when you want to fire the event
foreach(var listener in Listeners){
    listener(param1, param2);
}

// when you want to unsubscribe the listeners:
Listeners = new List<Func<T,S,U>>();
```

You can also use a weak collection if you want to avoid memory issues, removing listeners automatically as soon as the element gets garbage collected.

Comment: This is really a good answer. But worth noting that this isn't threadsafe (yet) and doesn't addresses how to unsubscribe particular event. I'm not sure `Listeners.Remove` would work.

Comment: Thread safety is not a concern with Unity, so for this particular scenario it may hold as a valid scenario. Thanks

Comment: Making it thread safe is only a matter of using a ConcurrentQueue so it's not a huge deal but good point :)

Comment: Making it thread-safe *is* a huge deal. Just enumerating a `ConcurrentQueue` implies a significant cost in terms of garbage (which you would not get using a regular `List` or `HashSet`).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to unsubscribe particular event, you can change the collection to HashSet. Then, you will remove a listener like:

```
private HashSet<Func<T,S,U>> listeners = new HashSet<Func<T,S,U>>();

public void RemoveListener(Func<T,S,U> listener){listeners.remove(listener);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer because this is the top result on Google right now:

According to [these tests](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3264), adding a function to a delegate creates 208 bytes of garbage, and adding delegates to an `event` creates 104 bytes multiplied by the number of events added. So the 10th delegate added to an event creates 1kb of garbage! I imagine a similar test for unsubscribing would have the same results. The two answers above implementing a custom event class using a `List` or `HashSet` have been an easy and effective solution for my own version of this problem in Unity.